# Need to create an update from a Join with nested selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:

```
SELECT users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       family_products.costs_obj
FROM   users
       JOIN family_products
         ON users.family_id = family_products.family_id
WHERE  users.family_id IN (SELECT family_id
                           FROM   employer_families
                           WHERE  employer_id = 117)
       AND family_products.product_id IN (SELECT id
                                          FROM   market_products
                                          WHERE  type = "medicalplan")
       AND users.first_name = 'alexandre'
```

And i need to be able to update cost_obj to = '' how would i run this select as an update?

Comment: Can you be bit more clear. Do you want to update another table with the `family_products.costs_obj` or something else

Comment: @pradeep yes, i need to update family_products.cost_obj

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not been able to test this, I think this is what you need:

```
UPDATE fp
  SET fp.costs_obj = ''
FROM
  users u
  JOIN family_products fp ON u.family_id = fp.family_id
WHERE
  u.family_id IN 
  (
    SELECT
      family_id
    FROM
      employer_families
    WHERE
      employer_id = 117
  ) 
  AND
  fp.product_id IN 
  (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      market_products
    WHERE
      type = "medicalplan"
  ) 
  AND
    u.first_name = 'alexandre';
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
  users u
  JOIN family_products fp ON users.family_id = fp.family_id
WHERE' at line 3

Comment: Your question is tagged as SQL SERVER! And I've fixed the aliased users. to u.

Comment: sorry thought i only put mysql and sql

Comment: still same error ->You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
  users u
  JOIN family_products fp ON u.family_id = fp.family_id
WHERE
  u' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this since I don't know the schema, but you can try this:

```
UPDATE family_products
SET costs_obj = ''
WHERE costs_obj IN(
    SELECT 
       family_products.costs_obj
    FROM   users
       JOIN family_products
       ON users.family_id = family_products.family_id
    WHERE  users.family_id IN (SELECT family_id
                           FROM   employer_families
                           WHERE  employer_id = 117)
       AND family_products.product_id IN (SELECT id
                                          FROM   market_products
                                          WHERE  type = "medicalplan")
       AND users.first_name = 'alexandre' 
)
```